# Float array not updating

Tags: arrays, list

I have an array of floating point numbers which represent the brightness of pixels from a black and white image.

So I load up an image, and the input array is populated.

For some reason though, when I load up a new image, which is different than the previous hence different pixels, the float array is still populated with the old data. What is going on?!

Adding elements into the array:

```
Bitmap I = new Bitmap(inputImage.Image);
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 28; j++)
    {
        input[count] = (I.GetPixel(i, j).GetBrightness());
        count++;
     }
 }
```

For some reason loading a new image doesn't overwrite the data in the array.

I'm setting the new image before updating the float array so the new image that is loaded is definitely being used in the nested for loop, but still doesn't want to cooperate.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reinitializing the array before the loop started?

Try this

```
Bitmap I = new Bitmap(inputImage.Image);
int count = 0;
input[]=[];
for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 28; j++)
    {
        input[count] = (I.GetPixel(i, j).GetBrightness());
        count++;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yea, didn't seem to help. I tried using lists before and clearing or reinitialise the list beforehand but neither worked.